# Moving to an EEA country as an EEA citizen

Tags: immigration

When they say EEA citizens have the right to "live, work, establish business and study" in another EEA country and this right is "up to three months".

If no other immigration route exists (EU national on another EU state, for example): What happens after this period? And what if some EEA national stays 89 days and then another 89 during the same year? Under what conditions, can they deny foreign EEA citizens to stay longer?

Comment: EEA states participate in the freedom-of-movement regime specified by [Directive 2004/38/EC](http://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX:02004L0038-20110616).  So the rules should be the same as those for an EU national in another EU state.